# Fetch image from list view using glide

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener, android-glide

I got images from my server as list view using Recycler, now I want to fetch image to another intent when we click the item using item click listener. I used glide but it shows only that particular image which we given. I want when I click one of the image in list, it must show that image in another activity.

```
Glide.with(SecondPage.this)
     .load("http://androidblog.esy.es/images/kitkat-9.png")
     .into(imageView);
```

Comment: it must show that image in another activity -> then pass it(URL) as a String using a bundle?

Comment: get Image url from the clicked listItem and pass to the next activity and then download image from url using glide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an `onClickListener` on `imageView`. Inside `onClick` method, write something like:

```
Intent intent = new (SecondPage.this, NewPage.class);
intent.putExtra("imageUrl", imageUrl);
startActivity(intent);
```

You should pass imageUrl similar `http://androidblog.esy.es/images/kitkat-9.png` over it.

On `NewPage` Activity. After `setContentView(R.layout.example)`, you declare `imageView` of `NewPage` activity.
Then write:

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null){
            String imageUrl = getIntent().getExtras().getString("imageUrl");
            Glide.with(NewPage.this).load(imageUrl).into(imageView);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> From your Recyclerview activity do this

```
String imageUrl = "http://androidblog.esy.es/images/kitkat-9.png";
Intent intent = new Intent(context, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("IMAGE_URL", imageUrl);
startActivity(intent);
```

> Now in NextActivity do this,

```
String imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("IMAGE_URL");
Glide.with(NextActivity.this).load(imageUrl).into(imageView);
```